# C# / ASP.NET MVC dependency injection with data repository isolated from web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, repository-pattern

I have a C# & ASP.NET MVC project using a `Repository` pattern with Ninject.

The current controller has all the injections for my data repositories that I guess I have to keep away of the `System.Web` assembly, because the data repository should only know about database and nothing else.

After reviewing my code I see that I have a dependency on `AppStateProvider`:

```
public class AppStateProvider : IAppStateProvider
{
    public Profile AppState
    {
        get
        {
            Profile appState = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["appstate"] != null)
            {
                appState = (Profile )HttpContext.Current.Session["appstate"];
            }
            return appState;
        }
    }
}
```

This dependency is registered in my `NinjectWebCommon.cs`:

```
  kernel.Bind(typeof(IAppStateProvider)).To(typeof(Helpers.AppStateProvider));
```

The concrete class `AppStateProvider` lives inside my `Web` project in a `Helpers` folder.

Now, on my data project I have the following repository that injects the dependency.

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    ILogManager _logManager = null;
    private readonly Profile _appState;

    public EmployeeRepository (IAppStateProvider appStateProvider, ILogManager logManager)
    {
        _appState = appStateProvider.AppState;
        _logManager = logManager;
    }

   // some methods here!!
}
```

So, I guess I'm doing the correct way because `Data Repository` still doesn't know anything about the application context (`HttpContext`) and If I reference the same `Data Repository` from a Windows Service project then my concrete class that will be injected instead of calling `HttpContext` to get the session might call database or other place to get the `Profile` object property. Am I correct?

Is there a way that instead of having this extra dependency `AppStateProvider` I can pass to the dependencies from my controller to the `Profile` object without passing it to each method as a parameter, like passing it as a property object maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown design already separates concerns via abstractions.

The composition root of the windows service project would just need to register the desired concrete implementation.

For example

```
//At the Composition Root of Windows Service

//...

windowsServiceKernel
    .Bind(typeof(IAppStateProvider))
    .To(typeof(WindowsServiceAppStateProvider));

//...
```

Where the concrete `WindowsServiceAppStateProvider` implementation lives inside the windows service project.

The data repository already explicitly states its required dependencies via  constructor injection.

Nothing else really to be changed here.